# Why is inbound IP for Azure webapp returning 404 for endpoints but using url works fine?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an .Net Core app published on Azure, the webapp has an endpoint that is publicly accesible.

When creating an HTTP POST request using the full url {azure-url}/results it works as expected. However a client needs to use this endpoint but his system transforms urls into IP addresses before creating a request (not sure why to be honest).

I've checked through Azure properties which is the IP address of the webapp which also matches when doing a `nslookup`. Problem is that when I replace the url with the IP address and make a request it returns 404.

Has anyone experienced something like this? I wonder if it's related to some Azure configuration I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Azure App Service is a multi-tenant service. Meaning that other apps may share the same servers and thus the same inbound IPs. In order for your request to be routed properly to your app, it needs the domain name, not just the IP.

There is a way to get a static inbound IP by [using a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip). I haven't tried that but I would assume even then you will not be able to call the service on that IP.

Comment: I just found on the documentation what you also are saying: "IP addresses are associated with function apps, not with individual functions. Incoming HTTP requests can't use the inbound IP address to call individual functions; they must use the default domain name " It seems that is not possible...