# Connect to Azure function app with private endpoint over VPN point to site

Tags: azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn, azure-dns

I've created an Azure function app, vnet, virtual network gateway, private endpoint, and private dns zone. My virtual network gateway is in its own subnet, below is relevant terraform from the `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway` resource

```
ip_configuration {
    name                          = "aza-vnet"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.vpn_gateway_public_ip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.vpn_gateway_subnet.id
  }
```

The private endpoint is created in a separate subnet in the same vnet, pointing to the function app. Below is some of the terraform configuration for that resource

```
private_service_connection {
    name                           = "oai-create-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.oai_create_app.id
    subresource_names              = ["sites"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "oai-create-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.create_func.id]
  }
```

I created the below dns zone

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "create_func" {
  name                = "privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
}
```

linked it to my vnet

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "create_func" {
  name                  = "oai-create-link"
  resource_group_name   = var.rg_name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.create_func.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}
```

and added an A record for the private endpoint ip

```
resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "create_func" {
  name                = "func-name.privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.create_func.name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.create_func.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
  #records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.create_func.ip_configuration[0].private_ip_address]
}
```

with `func-name` the name of my function.

I added the below to my vpn config file to try to use Azure DNS 168.63.129.16

```
<clientconfig i:nil="true">
    <dnssuffixes>
      <dnssuffix>.azurewebsites.net</dnssuffix>
    </dnssuffixes>
    <dnsservers>
        <dnsserver>168.63.129.16</dnsserver>
    </dnsservers>
  </clientconfig>
```

When I connect to my VPN and try to reach my function `curl https://func-name.azurewebsites.net/api/create` it doesn't resolve

When I use the private ip of the private endpoint `curl http://10.0.2.4/api/create` I get a 404, which is also unexpected but it is actually reaching the function app. Probably due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464153/why-is-inbound-ip-for-azure-webapp-returning-404-for-endpoints-but-using-url-wor)

Here is the output of `nslookup` which is resolving to a public ip

```
nslookup func-name.azurewebsites.net
Server:     10.16.80.1
Address:    10.16.80.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
func-name.azurewebsites.net canonical name = func-name.privatelink.azurewebsites.net.
func-name.privatelink.azurewebsites.net canonical name = hosts.func-name.azurewebsites.net.
Name:   hosts.func-name.azurewebsites.net
Address: 13.92.237.218
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get my function app hostname to resolve to the private endpoint ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what I can do to get my function app hostname to resolve to the private endpoint ip address?

To resolve the `function app` hostname to the private endpoint IP address, when using **Point to Site VPN**, you can add a **host entry** in local machine for the private endpoint to resolve the endpoint's IP address for testing.

```
Name: func-name.privatelink.azurewebsites.net
Address: 10.0.2.4
```

To add a host entry on your `local PC`, navigate to **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** and insert your entry into the `hosts file`.

[image]

As a permanent solution, consider implementing a Private `DNS Resolver` or a `custom DNS` server to resolve the IP address of the private endpoint when utilizing Point to Site VPN.

**Reference**:  [Point to Site VPN name resolution](https://github.com/dmauser/PrivateLink/tree/master/DNS-Integration-P2S#point-to-site-vpn-name-resolution-behavior)

[Private Endpoint DNS Integration Scenarios](https://github.com/dmauser/PrivateLink/tree/master/DNS-Integration-Scenarios#private-endpoint-dns-integration-scenarios)

Comment: Just wanted to add some clarification. If your point-to-site means you have a peered Windows network, you want a `conditional forwarder`. If my guess is wrong, you can see the different scenarios and choose the best option for your specific case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns-integration#on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder